# Axiomatic System for Propositional Calculus

Tags: logic

In Mendelson's book he sets out a formal axiomatic system from which he constructs a proof for $\mathscr{B}\rightarrow\mathscr{B}$.

As follows:
[image]
[image]
[image]

The application of modus ponens is clear, but how is it that the instances of the axioms are created? They clearly are not 1:1 the same as the axioms themselves, but they either seem to entail $\mathscr{B}$ or are entailed by $\mathscr{B}$. What is the process here?

Comment: An instance of an axiom schema is obtained replacing every occurrence of a schematic letter (like $C$ in $B \to (C \to B)$) with a formula (like $(B \to B)$); this is step 2 above.

Comment: I see! Is there a particular reason that C is chosen here? Could it have been done with B or D?

Comment: In what sense ? They are variables, like $x,y$ in algebra.

Comment: I'll check myself, instead of being lazy. But what I meant was, if $B\rightarrow B$ was chosen to replace $D$ in the schema A2 for step 1, would it still be possible to derive $B\rightarrow B$?

Comment: Oh... I see. Obviously, the answer is: you have to find the "right" substitution. There are techniques to find it, but basically you have to practice.

Comment: This question motivates a repetition of one of my favorite sermons: Don't just read the formulas. The prose that surrounds them is there for a reason. In this case, the first line of item 3 (before (A1)) seems to answer the question: The individual letters in (A1–3) stand for arbitrary wfs of $L$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The set of axioms is actually a set of axiom schemes, each one is infinitely many axioms, for each formula like $\mathscr{B}$ there exists a different axiom, but the whole point of proof writing which requires the human intelligence is to find the right axiom scheme and right instance of the axiom scheme to use in each step of the proof. That's the main challenge here, of course not any bad usage of the system would work.